# To get a block of rows around a specific date in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to extract a block (contiguous) of lines around a particular date specified by the presence (not `NaN` value) in `q1` column. By block I mean `k` days before the date and `p` days after the date.

For example, using the following dataframe, and setting `k=5`, `p`=2, I need to get the following blocks:

```
    participant_id response_date      q1  summary
0             11.0    2016-04-27     NaN      NaN
1             11.0    2016-04-30     NaN      2.0
2             11.0    2016-05-01  1089.0      3.0
3             11.0    2016-05-02     NaN      3.0
4             11.0    2016-05-03     NaN      3.0
5             11.0    2016-05-04     NaN      3.0
6             11.0    2016-05-05     NaN      3.0
7             11.0    2016-05-06     NaN      3.0
8             11.0    2016-05-07     NaN      4.0
9             11.0    2016-05-08     NaN      4.0
10            11.0    2016-05-09     NaN      3.0
11            11.0    2016-05-10     NaN      3.0
12            11.0    2016-05-11     NaN      3.0
13            11.0    2016-05-12     NaN      3.0
14            11.0    2016-05-13     NaN      3.0
15            11.0    2016-05-14     NaN      3.0
16            11.0    2016-05-15     NaN      3.0
17            11.0    2016-05-16     NaN      3.0
18            11.0    2016-05-17     NaN      4.0
19            11.0    2016-05-18     NaN      3.0
20            11.0    2016-05-19     NaN      3.0
21            11.0    2016-05-20     NaN      3.0
22            11.0    2016-05-21     NaN      4.0
23            11.0    2016-05-22     NaN      4.0
24            11.0    2016-05-23     NaN      4.0
25            11.0    2016-05-24     NaN      3.0
26            11.0    2016-05-25     NaN      3.0
27            11.0    2016-05-26     NaN      3.0
28            11.0    2016-05-27     NaN      3.0
29            11.0    2016-05-28     NaN      3.0
30            11.0    2016-05-29     NaN      3.0
31            11.0    2016-05-30     NaN      3.0
32            11.0    2016-05-31     NaN      4.0
33            11.0    2016-06-01     NaN      4.0
34            11.0    2016-06-02   802.0      3.0
35            11.0    2016-06-03     NaN      3.0
36            11.0    2016-06-04     NaN      3.0
37            11.0    2016-06-05     NaN      3.0
38            11.0    2016-06-06     NaN      3.0
39            11.0    2016-06-07     NaN      3.0
40            11.0    2016-06-08     NaN      3.0
41            11.0    2016-06-09     NaN      3.0
42            11.0    2016-06-10     NaN      3.0
43            11.0    2016-06-11     NaN      5.0
44            11.0    2016-06-12     NaN      3.0
45            11.0    2016-06-13     NaN      4.0
46            11.0    2016-06-14     NaN      4.0
47            11.0    2016-06-15     NaN      3.0
48            11.0    2016-06-16     NaN      3.0
49            11.0    2016-06-17     NaN      3.0
```

Block 1: (up to 5 days before the date where `q1` is not `NaN' and 2 days`

```
0             11.0    2016-04-27     NaN      NaN
1             11.0    2016-04-30     NaN      2.0
2             11.0    2016-05-01  1089.0      3.0
3             11.0    2016-05-02     NaN      3.0
4             11.0    2016-05-03     NaN      3.0
```

Block 2:

```
30            11.0    2016-05-29     NaN      3.0
31            11.0    2016-05-30     NaN      3.0
32            11.0    2016-05-31     NaN      4.0
33            11.0    2016-06-01     NaN      4.0
34            11.0    2016-06-02   802.0      3.0
35            11.0    2016-06-03     NaN      3.0
36            11.0    2016-06-04     NaN      3.0
```

I have implemented this algorithm in a quite straightforward way, with loops and conditional flows, however, that's pretty slow (for a large data set) and I would like to learn more paythonian/pandasian solution. I anticipate it may involve `groupBy` function.

Comment: @BradSolomon, it doesn't really matter, one can easily concatenate a list of data frames. I guess the easiest might be a multi-indexed df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a helper function to get a dict of DataFrames and concatenate them:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def get_block(obj, d, k, p):    
    # obj -> dataframe; d -> date
    start = d - relativedelta(days=k)
    end = d + relativedelta(days=p)
    obj = obj.set_index('response_date')
    return obj.loc[start:end]

dates = df[df.q1.notnull()]['response_date'].tolist()

result = {}
k = 5
p = 2

for d in dates:
    result[d] = get_block(df, d, k, p)

print(result[dates[0]])
               participant_id      q1  summary
response_date                                 
2016-04-27                 11     NaN      NaN
2016-04-30                 11     NaN      2.0
2016-05-01                 11  1089.0      3.0
2016-05-02                 11     NaN      3.0
2016-05-03                 11     NaN      3.0
```

Then you can just concatenate this result:

```
result = pd.concat((result))
result.index = result.index.rename(['mid_date', 'response_date']

print(result)
                          participant_id      q1  summary
mid_date   response_date                                 
2016-05-01 2016-04-27                 11     NaN      NaN
           2016-04-30                 11     NaN      2.0
           2016-05-01                 11  1089.0      3.0
           2016-05-02                 11     NaN      3.0
           2016-05-03                 11     NaN      3.0
2016-06-02 2016-05-28                 11     NaN      3.0
           2016-05-29                 11     NaN      3.0
           2016-05-30                 11     NaN      3.0
           2016-05-31                 11     NaN      4.0
           2016-06-01                 11     NaN      4.0
           2016-06-02                 11   802.0      3.0
           2016-06-03                 11     NaN      3.0
           2016-06-04                 11     NaN      3.0
```

I think a loop is pretty unavoidable here given that you may have overlapping sub-sections of your input.

Answer (score 2):

Since I do not have the starting code or data, I'll try my best. Given your response_date column is a datetime object

```
import datetime as dt
dates_not_null = your_df.loc[~your_df.q1.isnull(), 'response_date']
for i in dates_not_null:
    req_df = your_df.loc[(i - dt.timedelta(k)) : i + dt.timedelta(p)), :]
```

you can append this dataframe to a list and then concatenate or do whatever you want.